# How to modify admin pages?

Tags: views, theming

Everytime I log in into the Drupal site there is a resume of the posts that I have written. I would like to modify it and show all the accumulated views of each user post.

I plan to use the Views UI to make the query but I am not sure which file modify to change the admin site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are meaning the Drupal dashboard (admin/dashboard), there is a [documentation page](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/dashboard) on how to customize the dashboard.

If you want to go further on the customization of the dashboard, there are modules like [Homebox](https://drupal.org/project/homebox) that can be useful.